# D3 Brush and Zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to replicate something like this brush and zoom on my project: 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I am struggling with zoom feature to work on the chart properly. It should zoom the areas selected through the brush. I am calling following code on the chartGroup element but it is only zoom the firstChart and connections element and also not the selected area.  I feel that I shouldn't be calling this on the firstChart element, but I can't get this to work properly.

```
.call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoom));
```

Currently working code is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9ouNop0Z94kqeenUayeL?p=preview

Would be grateful for any assistance/guidance.  Thanks